# error while starting daemons in hadoop

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs

I am new to hadoop and trying to configure hadoop in pseudodistributed mode and when I try to start the daemons by the following command

bin/start-all.sh

and I get the following message

```
    starting namenode, logging to /data/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/bin/../logs/hadoop-waqas-namenode-trinity.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /data/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/bin/../logs/hadoop-waqas-datanode-trinity.out
localhost: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /data/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/bin/../logs/hadoop-waqas-secondarynamenode-trinity.out
localhost: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "localhost:9000"
localhost:      at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
localhost:      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
localhost:      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
localhost:      at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:146)
localhost:      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress(NameNode.java:156)
localhost:      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress(NameNode.java:160)
localhost:      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.initialize(SecondaryNameNode.java:131)
localhost:      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.<init>(SecondaryNameNode.java:115)
localhost:      at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode.main(SecondaryNameNode.java:469)
starting jobtracker, logging to /data/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/bin/../logs/hadoop-waqas-jobtracker-trinity.out
localhost: starting tasktracker, logging to /data/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/bin/../logs/hadoop-waqas-tasktracker-trinity.out
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address` property in `hdfs-site.xml`. When set to `:localhost:50090` I was getting the same error. You can leave it to the default value `0.0.0.0:50090` unless there is a port conflict.

Comment: thanks parveen. I got it right even with localhost. There was some other small stupid mistake I made in my configuration file.